# Recover long name of a section in beamer (nameref used)

Tags: beamer, sectioning, nameref

In beamer, I'm introducing a slide at the beginning of each section with

```
\usepackage{nameref}
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[scheme=esi-blue,shadow=true]{}
        \begin{center}
        \LARGE{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\currentname}}}
        \end{center}
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
    \end{frame}
}
```

The thing is, my section names are defined as, for instance, `\section[ASLR]{Defeating address layout randomisation}`
However, the slides introduced use the short name of the section (in the above example: "ASLR"), and I would like it to be the long name (in the above example: "Defeating address layout randomisation").

Any idea ? I've tried several things, but either it has similar results as the above code, or it behaves terribly with short section names in the small table of contents on the upper part of my slides (navigation option with beamer)

Comment: As always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you post a full but minimal self contained example that others can copy and test on their own. Here you only post a sniplet so people are more likely to pass on your question

Answer (score 1):

No need for external packages, you could simply use the beamer command `\insertsection`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[shadow=true]{}
        \begin{center}
        \LARGE\textcolor{gray}{\textbf{\insertsection}}
        \end{center}
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section[ASLR]{Defeating address layout randomisation}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]